# Html content based on argument

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to prepare such website that would change its content based on date argument.
It would be something really simple. Just add that argument in some urls and in the page content.
Something like this:

```
<h1>[date]</h1>
<p>File for today is <a href="/[date].mp3">here</a>.</p>
```

Where `[date]` is an argument. It would also be nice if I could add an url to page that would point to dynamically created page with given date. If it would make it easier I can use wordpress for this.

Where do I start?

Comment: Just have `date.php` be the link then in date.php do whatever needs to be done based on the date.

Comment: I could do something like this if I wanted to display content for today. But what do I do i I wanted to have an url that would point to content for `today -1` or `today -2`?

Comment: `date.php?day=-1` or `date.php?day=-2` could be used in that case. Something like`$date = !empty($_GET['day']) ? strtotime($_GET['day'] . ' days') : time();` (might want to verify `$_GET['day']` is a range you support).

Comment: Just replace the `[date]` with an actual PHP variable. Then just set that variable to what ever you want before that HTML. There isn't really enough information here for us to give a more specific answer. Try adding some proper examples of what you want and example data as well (so we know exactly what you expect)